# pygame How to add text to a rectangle to update only that text

Tags: python

so i am an absolute beginner in python and i dont understand how to add text into a rectangle. Here is the part of my code that im trying to fix. (I know this was asked before and i have read but not understood those ones, though i did try to make it work by following them. Unsuccesfully)
as reguested heres my error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aasi.py", line 46, in <module>
reset()
  File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\aasi.py", line 41, in reset
    status.rect = pygame.draw.rect(status.screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 240, 900, 100))
NameError: name 'status' is not defined
```

thanks in advance btw

```
def label3(itse, teksti, koko, väri, sijaintix, sijantiy):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("ubuntu-regular", koko)
    itse.screen.blit(font.render(teksti, True, väri), (sijantix, sijantiy)) #im pretty sure this is the problem.
    pygame.display.update()
    ruoka = 1
    juoma = 1
    energia = 1
    viihde = 1
def reset():
    cls()
    label("Olet aasi, mitä haluat tehdä?", 30, (255, 255, 0), 300, 50)
    label("Paina 1 syödäksesi." , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 80)
    label("Paina 2 juodaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 100)
    label("Paina 3 juostaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 120)
    label("Paina 4 nukkuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 140)
    label("Paina esc poistuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 160)
    status.rect = pygame.draw.rect(status.screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 240, 900, 100)) # this rectangle is the "status"
    label3(status.rect, "ruoka: " + str(ruoka), 35, (255, 255, 255), 40, 250) #these ones are suooised to be in the rectangle "status"
    label3(status.rect, "juoma: " + str(juoma), 35, (255, 255, 255), 40, 250) # ^
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please fix indentation. And add the error you're getting (if there is one, otherwise describe what's "broken").

Comment: Well now things are much clearer (although I fixed the indentations a bit more...). The error says `status` isn't defined. Is it? If so then where? The code should be an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.
Sorry if this is a bother, but you're gonna start getting down-votes if you don't play by the rules...

Comment: as i said im a beginner so its very messy and stupid

Comment: That's fine, I'm just saying your example should be complete and verifiable and minimal so as to help others help you. Back on topic - where is `status` defined?

Comment: Status is my rectangle, and it is defined on line 17 which is at the end

Comment: Then where did `status.screen` come from? I'll answer as best I can but again: minimal, complete, verifiable.

Comment: not sure at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i figured it out! (Big thanks to @ShlomiF)
I managed to make it work, by creating the rectangle as a subsurface to windowSurface.

```
def reset():
   cls()
   label("Olet aasi, mitä haluat tehdä?", 30, (255, 255, 0), 300, 50)
   label("Paina 1 syödäksesi." , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 80)
   label("Paina 2 juodaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 100)
   label("Paina 3 juostaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 120)
   label("Paina 4 nukkuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 140)
   label("Paina esc poistuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 160)
   pygame.display.update()
   pygame.display.set_caption("Aasipeli.pygame.debug")
   rect = pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, (2, 2, 2), (0, 0, 100, 100), 0)
   font = pygame.font.SysFont("ubunntu-regular", 30)
   text = font.render(str(ruoka), True, (0,255,0))
   windowSurface.subsurface(rect)
   windowSurface.subsurface(rect).blit(text, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to refer to a property/attribute/function/other of status, before status has been defined. so there's no `status.screen`, and no `status.rect`. You also can't do the following much simpler case:

```
a.b = 1
```

Unless `a` exists and has a property/attribute etc. called `b` before hand.
Seeing as you don't refer to anything other than `status.rect` and `status.screen` (at least in the code you gave), a simple solution would be to do-away with the whole `status` thing:

```
def label3(itse, teksti, koko, väri, sijaintix, sijantiy):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("ubuntu-regular", koko)
    itse.screen.blit(font.render(teksti, True, väri), (sijantix, sijantiy)) #im pretty sure this is the problem.
    pygame.display.update()
    ruoka = 1
    juoma = 1
    energia = 1
    viihde = 1
def reset():
    cls()
    label("Olet aasi, mitä haluat tehdä?", 30, (255, 255, 0), 300, 50)
    label("Paina 1 syödäksesi." , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 80)
    label("Paina 2 juodaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 100)
    label("Paina 3 juostaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 120)
    label("Paina 4 nukkuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 140)
    label("Paina esc poistuaksesi" , 20, (255,255,0), 300, 160)
    rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 240, 900, 100)) # this rectangle is the "status"
    label3(rect, "ruoka: " + str(ruoka), 35, (255, 255, 255), 40, 250) #these ones are suooised to be in the rectangle "status"
    label3(rect, "juoma: " + str(juoma), 35, (255, 255, 255), 40, 250) # ^
    pygame.display.update()
```

Hope that helps,
Good luck!

Comment: ill give it a go, seems like it will make sense, can the rectangle be named differently so i can do this multiple times simultaneously

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: by the way it gave me an error, different this time.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. Its just a variable name. Call it Dilbert if it makes you feel good, but that would be bad python zen.

Comment: @viluzi **M.C.V.E**. People won't go bug chasing with you this way. `ruoka` is defined in a different scope. But that's the most I'm prepared to do without being able to debug things _independently_.

Comment: I will accept your answer because it solved what i asked. ( just realised the variable that was not defined was not supposed to be in that part anyways.)

Comment: Good luck with the rest!!

Comment: Actually, sorry to bother you again, but that didnt solve my problem like i thought it did. When i fixed my variable declarations. I got another error telling me i cant use `itse.screen.blit` (you dont have to help me on this)

Comment: MCVE. There's no other way. I want to help but I can't help via your feedback and without a reproducible problem in my environment.